# Magento doesn't check php version

Tags: magento2, php, error, cron, xampp

I am using **Magento version 2.1.7**. 
When I install an extension in my magento it doesn't check php version.

Earlier it show that cron hasn't been configured yet error. For that I changed the cron check & updater check as **'success'** to skip the checking of cron. 
Now it is not checking the **php version** in my system.

My php version is 7.0.2 & I have set the **memory_limit=1024M** in **php.ini** file.

I am using XAMPP for the apache in windows.

Comment: I am using magento version 2.0.3, i need to upgrade using default methoid, how can i setup cron in localhost wamp windows.

Comment: There is no matter that which ever magento you are using, & this question is regarding run the default cron of magento.

Comment: If you want to setup cron for magento in your windows just do follow this link https://magecomp.com/blog/set-up-magento-2-cron-in-xampp-windows/

Comment: But I don't think that you need to setup any cron in windows for the upgradation

Comment: The above solved my issue as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am putting this answer that How it worked for me.

Went to Magento Directory opened CMD there & Ran below commands. To run the cron separately.

> Php bin/magento cron:run
>
> php update/cron.php
>
> php bin/magento setup:cron:run

Than ran the readiness check again & it worked.