# magento 2 showing wrong version of php

Tags: magento2, php, extensions, localhost

I am new to Magento.
I have installed **Magento 2.1.10** successfully and now I am trying to install **extension** to it. I got a free extension from the market place and while installing it, I am finding the following error in the readiness check.

1. **Wrong version of PHP**
2. PHP Settings Check *

> Your current PHP memory limit is 128M. Magento 2 requires it to be set
>   to 756M or more.

I have already set my memory_limit to 2G in the ini file.
    [image: Wamp Server selected version is 7.0.6]

Here is the screenshot of the readiness page

[image: readiness page]

Here **PHP version is 5.6.25**, but my **selected version is 7.0.6**.
Please help me get ride of these errors. Any help/suggestion us appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your **`Php.ini`** in your **`Wampp/Php`** folder & search for **memory_limit** set it to 2048M & save the file stop your Wampp server & **restart the Wampp Server** & try Again.

Be sure that after making your php version to 7.0.10 again **restart your server**.

For better information run your **info.php** file into your server & look for the active configurations are matching your requirements or not

Go to Magento Directory opened cmd/terminal there & Run these three commands in cmd/terminal. To run the cron separately.

> Php bin/magento cron:run
>
> php update/cron.php
>
> php bin/magento setup:cron:run

Try to run the readiness check again.See for the reference [Magento doesn't check php version](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181800/magento-doesnt-check-php-version)

If still facing some problem feel free to ask

Thank You!

Comment: Thank you for the advice,
i have done as you suggested but onrunning the final command on the command prompt I am getting the following error. Can you please suggest what to do??  


    [Exception]
  `Warning: ini_get() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in C:\wamp64\www\project\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\PhpRe
  adinessCheck.php on line 192`

Comment: The file name is **`PhpReadinessCheck.php`** & over there on line number 192  put this thing `$currentMemoryLimit = ini_get('memory_limit');`

Comment: Then try to again run the above command & if still facing any issue feel free to revert back

Comment: Hi again, I changed the line from `$currentMemoryLimit = ini_get('memory_limit', '2048M');` to `$currentMemoryLimit = ini_get('memory_limit');` but still not working. I am having the same issue. And also I have completed the previous steps successfully.

Comment: Update: Magento have passed the readiness check, but the PHP version is still wrong. It is still showing 5.6.25 instead of 7.0.6

Comment: run `info.php` on your server & see there which version it is showing there run this command in your cmd & see whether it is showing any error `php bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvv`

Comment: after doing changes in your server file make sure you stop your server & mysql & restart it & than test for the changes you made

Comment: execution of `php bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvv` never completes

Comment: what is your info.php showing?

Comment: run these two commands & try again to install the extension `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` & `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: Running the first command ended with the line "Please re-run Magento compile command". Second command ran various times. There are success counts and error counts as well after every check

Comment: for that you need to put `setup:di:compile` command as I directed on above. it will run till 7 messages if all are set then you are ready to go

Comment: for installing extension you can go with this answer [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189591/what-are-the-ways-for-installing-an-extension-in-magento-2/189598#189598](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189591/what-are-the-ways-for-installing-an-extension-in-magento-2/189598#189598)