# Cron Job has not been configured yet error on setup

Tags: magento2, cron, installation

Every time when I need to **install** anything (**Module**). I see this **readiness check** process and I see that the **check returns an error**.
I exchanged. **`setup_cronjob_status`** with [this](https://gist.github.com/mazhalai/ab290a1b96dea935c044)

All problems are fixed but this problem still I can't fix this

[image]

Comment: Try this & follow the steps it will solve your issue. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181800/magento-doesnt-check-php-version/183092#183092

Comment: On your magento2 root run:
magento cron:install
Ref:https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261065/cron-job-has-not-been-configured-yet-getting-magento-2-3

Answer (score 3):

As per error it says, your cron is not configured you have to configure cron scripts in order to get it work.

For more detail read this devdocs :

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html