# Cron job has not been configured yet getting magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.0

when I am trying to install extensions in Magento 2.3 getting an error Cron job has not been configured yet help me how to solve this

```
Error from Setup Application Cron Script:
Cron job has not been configured yet
Other checks will fail as a result (PHP version, PHP settings, and PHP 
extensions)

Error from Updater Application Cron Script:
Cron job has not been configured yet
```

Comment: So did You found different solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can run in console:

```
magento cron:install
```

This will add Magento cron configuration to your server.

After this check logs Magento directory .

From question we actually don't knoe did you installed Cron jobs , if yes do you have any logs?